# How to Compare 1st column in two worksheets and then check if another cell in matching row matches with corresponding cell in 2nd sheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been using vlookup my whole like but either I am brain-dead or for the love of God I am not able to figure this out.

I have two sheets:
Sheet 1

| REGION CODE | REGION NAME | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B01 | Region 1 | Open |
| B02 | Region 2 | Open |
| B03 | Region 3 | Closed |
| B04 | Region 4 | Closed |
| B05 | Region 5 | Open |

Sheet 2

| REGION CODE | REGION NAME | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B06 | Region 6 | Open |
| B07 | Region 7 | Open |
| B10 | Region 10 | Closed |
| B04 | Region 9 | Closed |
| B05 | Region 8 | Closed |

I want a formula on sheet 2 which should compare the REGION CODE column between the two sheets and if a matching data is found in sheet 1 then the compare the data in region name column from that row and tell me if the data in the region name column in sheet 2 is different than in sheet 1.

For example, in the above example, the matching REGION CODEs are B04 and B05 and the data in REGION NAME column has changed so the formula should either highlight it.

Thanks,

Comment: Use a `BOOLEAN` Logic within a `MATCH()` Function. And have you tried searching on **SO** there are similar queries as well!

Comment: `=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(Code, ... ,2,0)=Name, "Match", "Different"), "Not Found")`

Answer (score -1):

Use this below formula after place the table in next sheet and update the formula accordingly [tableCompare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e53yf.jpg)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).